# How to automatically on/off gmail vacation responder for daily on specific times?

Tags: gmail

How to automatically on/off gmail vacation responder for daily on specific times?

I want to turn on my vacation responder between 7 PM to 10 AM for each day of week.

Answer (score 1):

Vacation responder is designed to notify senders of your absence over periods of time longer than 15 hours. There is no way to automate it the way you are asking as it depends on server-side operations. What you can do is turn it & off on every day manually like an old-school answering machine.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do this? The vacation responder tells the person that emails you that you will not be in that business day. You don't use it to tell people you have gone home for the evening.

If this is for your business make a simple webpage and give your hours. Or use an auto responder to let them know you will respond within 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this [from within GMail](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=25922).

I think our best bet is to use some custom programming and the [Google API's](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/), or use a third party tool like SmartReply: http://www.smartreplyapp.com

Comment: But not free :(

Comment: The API's are absolutely free.  You are correct -- SmartReplyApp is not free currently.